# Конвертация BinnaryFile в byte[] русские буквы заменяются на?

Tags: c#, массивы, кодировка, byte

Формирую бинарный файл, потом создаю byte[] и отправляю на сервер. Сервер по логам говорит, что русские буквы заменяются на ???. Дополнительно попробовал сохранить byte[] в file.txt Почему так может происходить?

```
BinaryWriter myBinary = 
new BinaryWriter(File.Open("C:\\file.dat", FileMode.Create));
        myBinary.Write(stream.ToArray());
        myBinary.Close();
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\\file.dat");
```

Comment: Вообще у BinaryWriter есть конструктор, где можно указать кодировку. Вбейте туда UTF8 и не парьтесь. И у BinaryReader соответствии, так же укажите кодировку UTF8

Comment: Погодите, а что за stream вы используете? То есть вы текст записываете не с помощью BinaryWriter, а его используете только чтобы байты из потока записать в файл? Тогда нужно смотреть, как вы текст в этот поток stream записываете.

Comment: А вообще, для записи в файл уже готового массива байтов лучше использовать 'File.WriteAllBytes'. Создавать для этого BinaryWriter не обязательно.

Comment: @John Я создаю XML через XDocument, далее сохраняю в stream, для того чтобы у меня в массив байтов добавился заголовок xml для передачи в post запросе. Я изначально просто передавал xdoc как строку в массив, но это не работало, т.к. отсутствовал заголовок. Таким методом он появился, но вот засада теперь с кодировкой(

Comment: Тогда тут вопрос в том, как создать xml файл с нужной кодировкой. Само по себе xml файл - это текстовый формат данных, так что сохранение и передача в виде массива байтов проблем вызвать не может. Проблема именно в том, правильно ли кодируется текст в xml файле и правильно ли декдоруется этот файл потом.

Comment: Хм... По-моему, вам вообще не нужен `BinaryWriter`. В других ваших вопросах вы используете `WebRequest`, у него получаете поток вызовом `GetRequestStream` - вот в этот поток и пишите сразу, без промежуточных оболочек, с помощью `xdoc.Save(stream)`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а можно по подробнее? Я не совсем понял как это.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо за наводку. Это оказалось намного проще, и наверное правильнее.

Comment: Можете теперь сами дать ответ на свой вопрос. И принять потом его. И вам плюсик будет, и другим хорошо: кто будет искать ответы на похожие вопросы, быстро найдут. Причём у вас несколько вопросов по этой теме, можете все позакрывать своими ответами.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте для конвертации:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(someString);
```

Обратно:

```
string someString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

Для русских символов используйте `Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")` (для программ, которые не умеют работать с unicode и им нужно обязательно указывать "правильную" кодовую страницу символов) или `Encoding.UTF8` (для современных программ понимающих unicode и в которых сразу множество кодировок зашито)

См. также:

- [Converting string to byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16072742/5752652) Там описаны и другие кодировки, не только ASCII – но в общем-то главное, чтобы на обоих концах использовалась одна и та же кодировка.
- [MetaInt Чтение и запись файла](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/5.4.php) - пример на русском

Comment: Написано же, что русские буквы пересылаются, а вы в примере используете ASCII. Сразу делайте пример с нормальным кодировщиком, тем же UTF-8.

Comment: byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\\file.dat");
            string someString = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(byteArray);
            Console.WriteLine(someString);                                                                                 В консоль мне выдал нормально, без ???? В файл тоже конвертируется без ????, а вот когда отправляю в POST запрос этот массив, то на выходе у меня ????

Comment: @John Спасибо за уточнение, видимо ещё толком не проснулся. Поправил.

Comment: @AndreySherman POST запрос вы делаете в другое приложение, надо смотреть, какую он умеет кодировку (разные приложения могут работать с разными кодировками, неожиданно, да?), может как раз UTF8.

Comment: @AK Им надо windows-1251

Comment: @AndreySherman тут уже не кодировщик значит виноват. Либо что-то с данными происходит при отправке, либо на стороне сервера данные не так обрабатываются, либо вы не так кодируете.

Comment: @John Вот только что выяснили, что все же данные отправляются нормально, и в мою сторону формируется ответ, но при получении ответа,он рушится. Вот это уже странно.

Comment: @AndreySherman может вы ответ неправильным образом читаете? Если в ответе текст должен быть, то сохраните весь полученный поток на диск и откройте с помощью какого-нибудь продвинутого редактора, где можно на лету кодировку менять. Там пощелкайте по кодировками и посмотрите при какой кодировке текст получается. Чем черт не шутит... Может ответ вам в utf-8 приходит.

Comment: Именно так и получилось. Читал ответ тоже не правильно, разобрался наконец-таки с этим. Теперь все работает правильно.